# How to use the type "time" from the database in GORM?

Tags: mysql, go-gorm

In my structure I have a field like this:

```golang
type model struct {
    gorm.Model
    Time *time.Time `gorm:"type:time"`
}
```

It turns out that from what I could see, *GORM* uses the `time` type of *Go* itself and not the `time` type of the database, which was my intention.

This generates the following *sql* using the `Debug()` function:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `models` (`time` datetime(3) NULL)
```

And not:

```
CREATE TABLE `models` (`time` time NULL)
```

Want was what I expected.

How to make it work?

Even reading the documentation and other forums, everything I've tried has been useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of `GORM` database type mapping.

In `GORM`, the `time` in `type:"time"` is treating as a keyword to set the default database column type as `datetime` for mysql or `timestamptz` for postgresql.

the [schema](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/blob/e61b98d69677b8871d832baf2489942d79054a4a/schema/field.go#L48)

```
// GORM fields types
const (
    ....
    Time   DataType = "time"
    Bytes  DataType = "bytes"
)
```

**for MYSQL**

```
case schema.Time: 
        return dialector.getSchemaTimeType(field)
```

```
func (dialector Dialector) getSchemaTimeType(field *schema.Field) string {
    .... 

    if field.NotNull || field.PrimaryKey {
        return "datetime" + precision
    }
    return "datetime" + precision + " NULL"
}
```

**for POSTGRES**

```
....

case schema.Time:
        if field.Precision > 0 {
            return fmt.Sprintf("timestamptz(%d)", field.Precision)
        }
```

**Solution to set it as `time`**

You can use the [customisation](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html) approach provided by GORM.

> GORM will read column’s database `type` from tag type, if not found,
> will check if the struct implemented interface `GormDBDataTypeInterface`
> or `GormDataTypeInterface` and will use its result as data type

here is the snippet

```golang
type model struct {
    gorm.Model
    Time CustomTime
}

type CustomTime struct {
    time.Time
}

func (CustomTime) GormDataType() string {
    return "time"
}

func (CustomTime) GormDBDataType(db *gorm.DB, field *schema.Field) string {
    return "time"
}
```

**References** :

- [MYSQL DataTypeOf()](https://github.com/go-gorm/mysql/blob/91dcda2c6828a32ff45d6e01d971adab510f9fd9/mysql.go#L362)
- [Choosing the datatype for Time](https://github.com/go-gorm/mysql/blob/91dcda2c6828a32ff45d6e01d971adab510f9fd9/mysql.go#L407)
- [Customize Data Types](https://gorm.io/docs/data_types.html)